# pyqt5でQLabelのレイアウトがずれる

Tags: python, pyqt5

python3.5を使っています。pyqt5でレイアウトを試しているのですが、QLabelのレイアウトがずれてしまうのを直したいです。下が実際に書いたコードです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLCDNumber, QSlider, 
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        # ラベル名の設定
        lbl1 = QLabel('<h1>１行目<h1>')
        lbl2 = QLabel('<h1>２行目<h1>')
        lbl3 = QLabel('<h1>３行目<h1>')

        self.edit1=QLineEdit()
        self.edit2=QLineEdit()
        self.edit3=QLineEdit()

        btn1=QPushButton("1")
        btn2=QPushButton("2")
        btn3=QPushButton("3")

        firstlayout=QHBoxLayout()
        firstlayout.addWidget(lbl1)
        firstlayout.addWidget(self.edit1)
        firstlayout.addWidget(btn1)

        secondlayout=QHBoxLayout()
        secondlayout.addWidget(lbl2)
        secondlayout.addWidget(self.edit2)
        secondlayout.addWidget(btn2)

        thirdlayout=QHBoxLayout()
        thirdlayout.addWidget(lbl3)
        thirdlayout.addWidget(self.edit3)
        thirdlayout.addWidget(btn3)

        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(firstlayout)
        layout.addLayout(secondlayout)
        layout.addLayout(thirdlayout)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Absolute')    
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

そしてこれが得られたウィンドウです。
[image]

QLabelで書かれた個所が上にずれています。これを直したいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ラベルの設定箇所が`<h1>～</h1>`の様に閉じタグになっていないのが間違いではないでしょうか。

```
lbl1 = QLabel('<h1>１行目</h1>')
```

もしくは単に太字にするのが目的なら`<b>～</b>`を使うとか。

```
lbl1 = QLabel('<b>１行目</b>')
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！こんなに簡単になおるとは思っていませんでした！

Comment: 最終的にはどちら（閉じ忘れの修正 or 太字に置き換え）で意図した通りになりましたか？

Comment: どちらでもしっかりと修正されました

Comment: 太字の方は閉じタグになっていなくてもずれませんでした